# Farming underground

Tags: food, underground, sunlight, farming

Suppose the surface of earth is -349 Fahrenheit and survivors live deep underground dependent on geo-thermal energy.
They do farming in tunnels. They have enough energy (heat, electricity), fresh air (similar to the existing atmosphere, don't mind how for now) and water.
What kind of vegetables and fruits could they grow with artificial sunlight?

Comment: They probably couldn't grow anything thanks to lava streams.

Comment: Well they are not that deep. 300-400 meters down.

Comment: At about 300 metres below the surface, the temperature wouldn't increase enough to make a difference. It increases by 25 degrees Centigrade per 1km, which is about 1 degree Fahrenheit per 70 ft. So unfortunately, if the surface is -400 Fahrenheit (-240 C), there won't be any survivors at 300 metres. They'd have to go to about 16 km for the temperature to reach 0.

Comment: That's a good point, thx.So I will need to go further down and add artificial heating

Comment: Can you flesh out the question a bit? Do they have access to our level of tech or do they have limitations of any kind? Do they have any insects for pollination or can they manually pollinate the plants with flowers? Largely put: plants doesn't care if the light is artificial or not, as long as one can provide the proper wavelengths. So what plants they can grow partially depends on the type of light available and if the plants are able to reproduce or not.

Comment: They have higher technology than 2016. But not too futuristic. No insects at all. They should find another method.

Comment: @UKS you could try increasing the surface temperature instead. The lowest recorded temperature ever recorded on Earth was -95C/-138F. According to my rough Wikipedia calculations, they'd have to go to 3.8 km to balance that out, which is actually possible with current technology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TauTona_Mine

Comment: @PhilipRowlands Thx. My original idea is earth thrown out of orbit into deep space. That brings extreme cold. But cities must be way too deep. I will need to read some more geology.

Comment: It seems I can safely go down to 10 kms for 0 Celsius. But I will need to learn more. There can be other consequences I can not think of now.

Comment: /if the surface is -400 Fahrenheit (-240 C), there won't be any survivors at 300 metres./@Philip Rowlands.  I wonder about that.  I understood the subsurface at different depths to be at fairly constant temperature regardless of surface weather or temperature.   Also you have these folks dependent on geothermal so they may have sited their digs on a hot spot.  I would.

Comment: I think this may not be quite the right question.  with artificial lights they *could* grow anything that grow hydroponically, but if they have to convert thermal energy to electric to light to power plant growth that's going to be extremely inefficient.  while they could, and likely will do it to some degree, I suspect they would also be looking into grow more plants that don't require sunlight.  Fungus would be the obvious example, though there are other things that could grow based off of geothermal energy alone without sunlight.  Their prove easier to grow in quantity.

Comment: You could have cities at 300m as long as you just use heating. You could survive in pressurized habitats on the surface with heating. You would need to be at those spots where underground magma is very close to the surface though, if you want to power by geothermal. If you have nuclear power you'd be fine at any depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that can be grown hydroponically could be grown in the tunnels.  So just about anything.  Probably not mangoes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if they REALLY wanted to they could grow a mango as well.
After all, soil isn't much more than minerals and dead organic stuff, and you have enough of both (you just need the necessary microfauna, but that should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring how deep they actually have to be (much much deeper than 300m) , **they could grow anything**.

Without insects, anything requiring pollination will have to be done manually, making it immensely labor intensive, but apart from that they're perfectly fine.

The first generation could only be hydroponic-able stuff, but after a while they have enough organic waste for regular soil, removing the last limit for what they can grow.

[Sidenote since you want to shoot your planet out of orbit: Stone is a bad insulator, but there are enough theories about life on extraorbital planets, copy from them what is theorized to be insulating enough]