# Underwater Farming

Tags: engineering, underwater, colonization, agriculture, farming

In my colonizing business, some colonists build a underwater base on a all-about nice planet. They are using food storage right now; but now they need to start farming. Ive looked up [some farming things](https://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2015/aug/13/food-growing-underwater-sea-pods-nemos-garden-italy). They have set aside lots of resources and space to build the farm, whatever it is.

My question is:

**How can I make large industrial scale underwater farming?**

**What can they farm, animals and plants?**

I live in a agricultural community so I will understand agricultural stuff.

Comment: Hi Aaron, this is a cool question but is also very broad. Your two questions would be better broken up into two separate ones, and each of them is individually probably too broad. Can I recommend our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for further help fitting within the scope of the site?

Comment: Please keep in mind that in your example of underwater farming, pods sit at depth 5 to 8 m. This is Ok for the required amount of light, but if your colony needs to be deeper, farming will be different.

Comment: are you limited ot salt water, or can they farm in fresh water. wild rice, water caltrop, Chinese water chestnut, Indian lotus, water spinach  and watercress are all fresh water farmables.

Comment: You've indicated that you don't like L.Dutch's answer because it isn't far enough underwater. In that case, you have an underspecified question. Please specify exactly how far underwater you want, or other constraints to narrow the question. Otherwise, as has been pointed out, this is too broad.

Comment: [Aquaculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaculture) is a rapidly-growing business in my state, but it's primarily about the growing of seafood (fish, clams, etc) and not about typical terrestrial vegetables.  Are your farmers trying to produce all their own food? Or would they be happy growing seafood as a cash crop, to sell it and buy the other foods they want to eat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water farming is already done by the land dwelling hairless apes on planet Earth, and they both farm plants and animals.

For plants, look at nori. Nori is that seaweed that one finds around sushi, onigiri or in Japanese ramen.

It is [farmed in water](http://www.seaweed.ie/aquaculture/noricultivation.php) (and from the picture below I would see it is already large scale), and the only out of water step is the drying.

[image: Nori farm]

For animals, think of pearl cultivation or fish farms: instead of harvesting from above the surface, one can harvest from below, all the rest staying the same.

[image: fish farm]

One just need a sheltered area (no strong waves or currents), with good nutrients supply and adequate temperatures and water conditions.

Nothing really different than what a farmer seeks for his land farm, at the end of the day.

Comment: This Is an excellent answer, but im looking for something like https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70997/farming-underground?rq=1, just deep underwater. (sorry if this is not proper etiquette, im learning)

Comment: @Aaron, the deeper you go, the less light you get and the less you can farm. Also, these example are right on the surface because they are accessed from it. They can be placed a tad deeper with no big impact.

Comment: I see what you mean, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Also consider shellfish, humans farm a large number of shellfish and they don't require much alteration to the terrain.